# How to display a bitmap image in Android imageview

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, bitmapimage

I am new at Android. Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(nadraData.image, 0, nadraData.image.length); 
    

((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_user)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    

Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated: bitmap is "+bitmap );
```

Comment: Please add in the whole code of how your are showing bitmap in imageview

Comment: And tell what was logged.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
byte[] decodedString = 
Base64.decode(person_object.getPhoto(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
user_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Isnt there a .decodeByteArray()? Then you would not need an intermediate stream.